# How to remove sub menu page in WP admin which uses admin.php and a query string

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

How do I remove a sub-menu with link
`http://vagrant.local/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=home_settings_page` ?

I tried `remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'yrc_home_settings_page' );`
but that didn't work.

### Edit

```
function remove_menu_pages_for_fuel_surcharge_editor() {
    if(current_user_can('fuel-surcharge-editor')) {
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');
        remove_menu_page('options-general.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=show_event');
        remove_menu_page('jetpack');
        remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'yrc_home_settings_page' );
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_pages_for_fuel_surcharge_editor', 999);
```

I also tried which didn't work either.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_menu_pages_for_fuel_surcharge_editor', 999);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need to add the function to a hook.  Try something like:

```
function remove_submenu() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'yrc_home_settings_page' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_submenu', 999 );
```

I'm not entirely sure if the second parameter in your function is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am actually using a hook already, but was missing the priority value. However, even adding the priority doesn't work! Updated my question with the function and the hook.

Comment: No problem.  When you hover over the parent menu, what is the URL? I assume admin.php?

Comment: If the parent is definitely admin.php, try these: remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'admin.php?page=home_settings_page' ); or remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', '?page=home_settings_page' );

Comment: Tried both but none of them worked :(. Attached a screenshot. I want to remove the item "Home Page Settings"

Comment: What URL do you see when you hover over 'YRC Settings'?

Comment: I got it finally! It should be `remove_submenu_page( 'yrc_settings_page', 'yrc_home_settings_page' );` following the syntax `remove_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $menu_slug );` You showed me the way. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah!! no. I am still not done. I need to remove the main menu item because it points to `http://vagrant.local/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=yrc_settings_page` which I need to remove as well. Sorry to bother you again. How can I remove this main menu and just show the sub-menu? Actually it is done. Both links now point to the right place. I got confused. Your suggestion really showed me the way. Thanks again!